# are object files functionally the same when compiled with or without precompiled headers?

Tags: c++, c, build, compilation, precompiled-headers

Can you swap around an object file that was compiled with PCH or not (assuming the same source/flags) in a particular link job? For MSVC? for Clang? for GCC?

I know in some cases, MSVC creates PCH object files that need to be linked in along with the normal object files, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation (for MSVC, clang, gcc) that was definitive about if the object files are functionally the same when they go to the linker step.

Edit:
For GCC, it seems the resulting object file is larger in size when compiled with PCH, which would seem to indicate it is not functionally the same, but most documentation only talks about PCH in context of the compiler not the linker, which indicates otherwise.

Comment: Removed the C tag. C has no use for precompiled headers.

Comment: *I know MSVC creates PCH object files that need to be linked in* ... presumably, only if you use the link-time code-generation flag(s).

Comment: @user4581301 _C has no use for precompiled headers._ Really?  That statement is certainly not true for MSVC.  Compiling `windows.h` to a precompiled header is a big win (in terms of compilation times), for example, in larger projects.

Comment: So be it. Reverting.

Comment: _I know MSVC creates PCH object files that need to be linked in_ What makes you say that?  It doesn't match my experience.

Comment: I've never had to link in a precompiled header on any platform I've worked on.  The one's I've used have been fed into the compiler to improve the performance of the translation unit.  They've not been fed into the linker.  But maybe things have changed since I've last fiddled with the details.

Comment: I do not think pre-compiled headers are used by linker in any system. All the systems I have seen use precompiled headers as input to the compiler. In particularly, gcc is very clear on that: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html Why don't you check yourself? Compile the same file with and without precompiled headers and check `.o` file which was generated?

Comment: @SergeyA I am planning to test myself, but more over I am wondering if there is any official documentation on the matter I looked through the obvious places, and I didn't find anything definitive on this questions. Just because I try it out and it works doesn't mean I should do it.

Comment: @dmoody256 I am not familiar with MSVC. gcc is very clear on the fact that it pre-compiled headers are used as an input to the compiler, see the link I have posted above.

Comment: @dmoody256: I believe the answer to the question of "is the intermediate object file from a translation unit the same whether PCH is used or not" is supposed to be "yes", but since it's not a standard part of the C++ language it will depend on your compiler/platform's implementation.

Comment: @AndyG okay but why are the object files bigger (at least my testing with GCC) when using PCH?

Comment: It all depends.  If the precompiled header has some global variables and without doesn't have global variables, you'll have a difference in object file.  Best practice is to only include the header files you need.

Comment: @dmoody256: There could be headers pulled into translation units by the PCH that otherwise weren't used? It's a bit of an art form on deciding what does and does not go into your PCH